# Pytest monkeypatch mock leak

Tags: python, redis, mocking, pytest, monkeypatching

I have a module that I am trying to unit test, and when running individual tests by themselves, each test will pass. When I try to run the full set of tests together in a single test session using `pytest test_some_module.py`, some tests will fail due to a monkeypatch mock that is leaking across tests.

I have an example module, `handler.py` that is as follows:

```py
import os

from redis import Redis

host = os.environ["REDIS_HOSTNAME"]
r = Redis(host=host, db=0)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """Lambda Handler"""

    for key, value in event.items():
        r.set(key, value)

    keys = r.keys()
    return keys
```

Then I have a test module, `test_redis.py`, with the following code:

```py
import pytest
import redis
from fakeredis import FakeRedis


@pytest.fixture()
def hostname():
    return "a fake host"


@pytest.fixture()
def fake_redis(hostname):
    return FakeRedis(host=hostname, db=0)


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_redis(monkeypatch, fake_redis, hostname):
    def _redis(*args, **kwargs):
        return fake_redis

    monkeypatch.setattr(redis, "Redis", _redis)
    monkeypatch.setattr(redis, "StrictRedis", _redis)
    monkeypatch.setenv("REDIS_HOSTNAME", hostname)


def test_cache_is_set(hostname):
    from handler import lambda_handler

    result = lambda_handler({"a_key": "value"}, {})
    assert len(result) == 1


def test_cache_is_empty(hostname):
    from handler import lambda_handler

    result = lambda_handler({}, {})
    assert len(result) == 0
```

When I go to run either of the test functions by themselves, they will pass.
However, when I run `pytest test_redis.py`, the `test_cache_is_empty` unit test will fail due to keys being present in the monkeypatched Redis database using `FakeRedis`.

This is failing for me on Linux. Is there a good way to do this to ensure that mocked objects don't leak across unit tests?

I'm using `pytest 6.2.4` and `fakeredis 1.6.0`.

For context, I have tried adding the following code to the `mock_redis` test fixture and it still won't work as intended.

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_redis(monkeypatch, fake_redis, hostname):
    def _redis(*args, **kwargs):
        return fake_redis

    monkeypatch.setattr(redis, "Redis", _redis)
    monkeypatch.setattr(redis, "StrictRedis", _redis)
    monkeypatch.setenv("REDIS_HOSTNAME", hostname)
    yield
    fake_redis.flushall()  # <- This should work and flush the db for the next test function to use
```

Comment: Might bring up performance, but am I right that you want each fixture to be isolated for each test, to avoid conflicts when running all tests?

Comment: Yes @enslaved_programmer, that is correct. If my understanding of pytest is correct, unless the scope of a test fixture is specified, it should default to function scope, where each function gets its own implementation of each test fixture.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, `function` is the default scope. Please try to set `scope=session` inside each fixture.